# How to extract values from the Landsat image and plot the spectral profiles of the different materials in R

Tags: r, shapefile, r-raster, rgdal

I have a shapefile for an area that I would like to get the spectral profile of different materials in the area for example water, roads, or vegetation. Something that looks like this?

[image: Spectral Profile Graph]

What would be the best way to do this?

I have loaded the shapefile in r but not sure how to extract the values from the Landsat raster stack.

````
```{r}
landsat<-stack(B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7)
roi <- readOGR("roi.shp")
shapes
```
````

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
df = raster::extract(landsat,     # raster layer
    roi,                       #shapefile
    fun=mean,         # what value to extract
    df=TRUE)          # return a dataframe
```

Your raster object and roi should have same coordinate system.